# Peg Solitaire variant: from 48 on an 8x8 board

Tags: strategy, board-games

Looking at David Ahl's [Basic Computer Games,](https://www.atariarchives.org/basicgames/) one of the programs that caught my eye was [One Check](https://www.atariarchives.org/basicgames/showpage.php?page=122).

It's like Peg Solitaire, which I've figured, but it's on an 8x8 board with the 4x4 inner bit hollowed out. I am wondering how to leave just one peg on the board.

```
  01234567
0 xxxxxxxx
1 xxxxxxxx
2 xx....xx
3 xx....xx
4 xx....xx
5 xx....xx
6 xxxxxxxx
7 xxxxxxxx
```

By standard Peg Solitaire methods of getting rid of 3 at a time, I've managed to get down to 3 checkers in a row, which isn't good enough. You need a peg, something one square away, and something a knight's move away.

For instance, I could pick off the edge squares moving (2,0) to (2,2) and (0,0) to (2,0) and (0,1) to (2,1). And rotating that to the other corners. That seems to be a good start. Obviously, I can't keep everything symmetrical forever.

```
  01234567
0 ..xxxx..
1 ..xxxx..
2 xxx..xxx
3 xx....xx
4 xx....xx
5 xxx..xxx
6 ..xxxx..
7 ..xxxx..
```

My almost-solution after removing the corners is spoilered:

> (30,32) (50,30) (20,40) (51,31) (32,30) (40,20) (12,32) (20,22) (32,12) (02,22) (03,23) (22,24) (05,03) (15,13) (03,23) (37,35) (35,15) (23,25) (15,35) (27,25) (25,45) (55,35) (47,45) (57,55) (74,54) (54,56) (35,55) (56,54) (75,55) (55,53) (52,54) (62,64) (72,74) (64,44)

What is a full solution? How do I disrupt my symmetry or general strategy at the right time? I'm probably getting lazy at the final hurdle, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you assume the standard peg solitaire rules.

Then a solution is

> impossible. Take a look at the 3-colouring of the board below. Initially the 48 pegs are placed in squares such that there are 16 of each colour (indicated by capital letters). Every move you make removes a peg from two of the colours and adds a peg of the third colour. This means that in every move for each colour the number of pegs of that colour changes parity from even to odd or vice versa. At the start there is an even number of pegs of each colour, so at the end the number of pegs of each colour will all be even or all be odd. Having a single peg of one colour at the end violates that criterion. The best you can hope for is ending with two pegs of the same colour (and zero pegs of the other two colours).
>
> ```
> A B C A B C A B
> B C A B C A B C
> C A b c a b C A
> A B c a b c A B
> B C a b c a B C
> C A b c a b C A
> A B C A B C A B
> B C A B C A B C
> ```

The game at the link however allows diagonal jumps as well.

> The colouring above shows that at least one jump is needed in a direction along one diagonal axis, and by using the same colouring rotated a quarter turn you find that you need at least one jump along the other diagonal axis as well.
>  I don't have a solution for this version, but I am confident that one can be found.

Comment: Ah, I thought there was some sort of parity argument! I even considerd this. But I didn't nail it down. Thanks so much.

And yes, I suspect it would be a lot easier with diagonal movements. I just didn't notice that! Well, the problem was more interesting this way, and your reasoning probably provides a general solution to other puzzles.

Comment: Checking the linked page for myself, not only are diagonal moves permitted, they appear to be the *only legal moves.*

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem In that case it is equivalent to two instances of normal peg solitaire (the two colours of a checkerboard colouring), and you still can't reduce it to one peg.